# Work with html-element width when change scale of browser

Tags: html, css, width

I have the folowing html-murkup structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="my_line"></div>
</div>
```

Wrapper has width `1200 px`. I want to make `div.my_line` to has width 100%  of screen when user change scale of screen. How can I do this? I try to use `background-repeat`, I am new in frontend, can somebody help me?

Comment: could you explain further "_when user change scale of screen_"?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, I mean when I use browser zoom.

Comment: The link may helps you. Change height parts with width: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Comment: On which resolution or screen width you want to see it 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just guessing here but you want the my_line div to stretch 100% of the width once the screen is at 1200px?

If so you'd use this:

```css
/* Check the screen width, in this case looking for the screen to reach 1200px or below. Then extend the my_line div to 100% */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .wrapper .my_line {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want the `my_line` to be the same size as the `wrapper` and shrink when you resize the window use this approach :

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper .my_line {
    width: 100%;
}
```

That way `wrapper` will have 100% of the browser but be limited and always centered. While the `my_line` will inherit the full width.

So, when you resize, to less than 1200px the `wrapper` and `my_line` will shrink with the window.

### EDIT:

If you want the `my_line` to be bigger than the `wrapper`, why placing it inside the `wrapper` ? Just place it above or underneath of the `wrapper`.

The solution you got works anyways if you change the HTML. The problem with your solution is that if you later add `position: relative` to the `wrapper` it won't work. While if you change the HTML structure so that `my_line` is direct children of the `body` it will still work.

Comment: Fixed, missing the space in the selectors. Ty.

Comment: Ok..but now the internal div will also be limited to 1200px.

Comment: I think that's what OP is trying to achieve but keep it on resize to full-width of the browser.

Comment: Nope...he wan's it 100% width of the screen **regardless** of the wrapper's width. Anyway, he's answered his own question.

Comment: Oh i see.. Got the question wrong. Fixing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I do this and it help:

```
.my_line {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 3px;
}
```

Comment: this is going to be always 100% while in your question you have mention when user resize browser.